# PHP DI pattern for function driven application

Tags: php, unit-testing, dependency-injection, containers

I have some classes that require dependencies injected into their constructors. This allows me to inject mocks (e.g. from [prophecy](https://github.com/phpspec/prophecy)) for testing.

I'm interested in using a container to help configure and access these objects, and I've looked at [Pimple](https://github.com/silexphp/Pimple) for this (I also looked at [PHP-DI](https://github.com/PHP-DI/PHP-DI) although I couldn't get that to resolve stuff on a quick attempt).

All good so far. **BUT**, the problem I have is that the application (Drupal 7) is built around thousands of functions which do not belong to an object that can have dependencies injected into.

So I need these functions to be able to access the services from the container. Further more, for testing purposes, I need to replace the services with mocks and new mocks.

So the pattern is like:

```
<?php
/**
  * Some controller class that uses an injected mailing service.
  */
class Supporter
{
  protected $mailer;

  public function __construct(MailingServiceInterface $mailer) {
     $this->mailer = $mailer;
  }

  public function signUpForMalings($supporter_id) {
     $email = $this->getSupporterEmail($supporter_id);
     $this->mailer->signup($email);
  }
}
```

Then peppered in various functions I'd use:

```
<?php
/**
  * A form submit handler called by the platform app,
  * with a signature I can't touch.
  */
function my_form_submit($values) {     
  global $container;

  if ($values['subscribe']) {
    $supporter = $container->get('supporter');
    $supporter->signUpForMailings($values['supporter_id']);
  }
}
```

Elsewhere I may need to access the mailer directly...

```
<?php
/**
  * example function requires mailer service.
  */
function is_signed_up($email) {
   global $container;
   return $container->get('mailer')->isSignedUp($email);
}
```

And elsewhere a function that calls those functions...

```
<?php
/**
  * example function that uses both the above functions
  */
function sign_em_up($email, $supporter_id) {
  if (!is_signed_up($email)) {
    my_form_submit(['supporter_id'=>$supporter_id);
    return TRUE;
  }
}
```

Let's acknowledge that these functions are a mess - that's a deliberate representation of the problem. But let's say I want to test the `sign_em_up` function:

```
 <?php
public testSignUpNewPerson() {
   $mock_mailer = createAMockMailer()
     ->thatWill()
     ->return(FALSE)
     ->whenFunctionCalled('isSignedUp', 'wilma@example.com');

   // Somehow install the mock malier in the container.

   $result = sign_em_up('wilma@example.com', 123);
   $this->assertTrue($result);
}

// ... imagine other tests which also need to inject mocks.
```

While I recognise that this is using the container as a Service Locator in the various global functions, I think this is unavoidable given the nature of the platform. If there's a cleaner way, please let me know.

However my main question is:

There's a problem with injecting mocks, because the mocks need to change for various tests. Lets say I swap out the mailer service (in Pimple: `$container->offsetUnset('mailer'); $container['mailer'] = $mock_mailer;`), but if Pimple had already instantiated the `supporter` service, then that service will have the old, unmocked mailer object. Is this a limitation of the containter software, or the general container pattern, or am I Doing It Wrong, or is it just a mess because of the old-school function-centred application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I've gone for, in absence of any other suggestions!

### Container uses `Pimple\Psr11\ServiceLocator`

I'm using Pimple, so the container's factories may look like this

```
<?php
use Pimple\Container;
use Pimple\Psr11\ServiceLocator;

$container = new Container();
$container['mailer'] = function ($c) { return new SomeMailer(); }
$container['supporters'] = function ($c) {
  // Create a service locator for the 'Supporters' class.
  $services = new ServiceLocator($c, ['mailer']);
  return new Supporter($services);
}
```

Then the Supporter class now instead of storing references to the objects extracted from the container when it was created, now fetches them from the ServiceLocator:

```
<?php
use \Pimple\Psr11\ServiceLocator;
/**
  * Some controller class that uses an injected mailing service.
  */
class Supporter
{
  protected $services;

  public function __construct(ServiceLocator $services) {
     $this->services = $services;
  }

  // This is a convenience function.
  public function __get($prop) {
    if ($prop == 'mailer') {
      return $this->services->get('mailer');
    }
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Unknown property '$prop'");
  }

  public function signUpForMalings($supporter_id) {
     $email = $this->getSupporterEmail($supporter_id);
     $this->mailer->signup($email);
  }
}
```

In the various CMS functions I just use `global $container; $mailer = $container['mailer'];`, but it means that that in tests I can now mock any service and know that all code that needs that service will now have my mocked service. e.g.

```
<?php
class SomeTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
   function testSupporterGetsMailed() {
      global $container;

      $supporter = $container['supporter'];

      // e.g. mock the mailer component
      $container->offsetUnset('mailer');
      $container['mailer'] = $this->getMockedMailer();

      // Do something with supporter.
      $supporter->doSomething();

      // ...
   }
}
```